# Is a number an integer ? (with xfp or pgfmath or expl3 )

Tags: expl3, pgfmath

I continue to test the transition from **fp** to **xfp**. The results are good but two macros resist: `\FPifint` and`\FPClip`. I did not find how to replace them in **xfp**.
I have numbers (decimal numbers [+,-,0,...,9 and "."] only). I want to know if a number is an integer but with the first  condition (there is a second ...) :

1.0 , 15.00 etc .. are integers

`\FPifint` works like this. I found some solutions but not entirely satisfactory and I prefer to avoid loading another package.

1. **biblatex**  with `\ifinteger` (not test)
2. **xstring** with  `\IsInteger` (I don't need all the stuff)
3. **Memoir** with `\checkifinteger`(wrong solution)
4. **lua** with `lua_isinteger` (not test)

I tried to find a personal solution :

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex-dev

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp,pgffor} 
 %xfp because i wanted to use \fpeval for some tests
\newif\ifinteger

\makeatletter
\def\removedot#1.{#1}
\newcommand\getinteger[1]{\expandafter\@getinteger#1.\@nil}
\def\@getinteger#1.#2\@nil{%
  \ifx\empty#2\empty
    \integertrue
    \else
    \ifnum\removedot#2=0   
        \integertrue
     \else 
       \integerfalse
     \fi
  \fi
}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
\foreach \value in {+1 ,-1.00,0.75,10000,0.9998}{
\getinteger{\value}
\ifinteger
\value{} is considered an integer
\else
\value{} is not considered  an integer
\fi
\\}

\end{document}
```

Firstly I'm not sure if my code is correct and I would like to know how to translate this with expl3 (or perhaps the macro  comes with xfp ?)

I'm also looking for a macro to remove all unnecessary zeros from a decimal like `FPClip`

There is another condition: I would like to accept as integers, decimal numbers ending for example with 999. Thus 1.999 or .999 will be considered as decimal. With my code the idea was to test # 2 but I did not find a satisfactory method

[image]

Comment: you can test if round(#1)=#1 or given your final note check that abs(round(#1)-#1)<.001

Comment: How you write the test with `xfp`. I don't know the syntax .. There is no example in the doc.

Comment: we are working on the doc but `texdoc interface3` then look at the l3fp chapter shows the syntax, I'll post something here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just use fpeval and a latex2e test but I use an expl3 conditional here

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\test[1]{
\fp_compare:nTF{0.01 < abs(round(#1)-#1)}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}


10 \test{10}{no}{yes}


9.99 \test{9.99}{no}{yes}

1.2 \test{1.2}{no}{yes}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's on my todo list : learn how to use expl3. Thanks it's the beginning of a great learning

Comment: Is it a problem in a package to mix latex2e and expl3 ?

Comment: @AlainMatthes that is the exact purpose of expl3, to make the l3 programming layer available in 2e documents and packages